# Iterate through multiple lists and a conditional if-statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to iterate through 3 lists where the first list is conditional (1 or 0)
if list1 == 1: print('Some text', **item0 in list2**, 'Some text' **item0 in list2**, 'some text', item0 in list3)

This is my code

```
dicts = {0:1, 1:1, 2:1}
values = list(dicts.values()) #Makin a list from values in my dict (1 or 0) my new list now contains [1, 1, 1]

cells = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI']
nodes = ['123', '456', '789']

for v, c, n in zip(values, nodes, cells):
    if v == 1:
        print('Some Text ', n, ' Some Text', n, 'text', c, 'Some Text')
```

I want the result to end up with:

```
Some Text 123 Some Text 123 text ABC Some Text
Some Text 456 Some Text 456 text DEF Some Text
Some Text 789 Some Text 789 text GHI Some Text
```

I've tried multiple approches but i cant seem to get it right

Comment: Presumably `zip(values, nodes, cells)` should be `zip(values, cells, nodes)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just inverted `c` and `n` in your loop:

```
for v, n, c in zip(values, nodes, cells):
    if v == 1:
        print('Some Text', n, ' Some Text', n, 'text', c, 'Some Text')
```

*NB. you don't need to add spaces around the chunks if using print with many parameters*

output:

```
Some Text 123 Some Text 123 text ABC Some Text
Some Text 456 Some Text 456 text DEF Some Text
Some Text 789 Some Text 789 text GHI Some Text
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your print statement by this

```
print('Some Text ', c,'Some Text ', c, ' text', n,  'Some Text')
```